# call gRPCTargets.cmake can't found libgpr.so

Tags: grpc

I import grpc project use `gRPCConfig.cmake` file. But the following error occurred

> CMake Error at `/home/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a53+neon-vfpv4_glibc-2.22_eabi/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake:178 (message)`:

The imported target "gRPC::gpr" references the file

```
 "/usr/lib/libgpr.so"
```

but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

- The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  The installation package was faulty and contained

```
/home/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a53+neon-vfpv4_glibc-2.22_eabi/usr/lib/cmake/grpc/gRPCTargets.cmake
```

but not all the files it references.

Comment: yes, it is  the cross-compiled environment. I try to modify the variables of `_IMPORT_PREFIX` with correct path. but always not found.

Comment: Importing grpc using into other projects currently has its flaws  (build works & is tested). Please look at already existing cmake issues on https://github.com/grpc/grpc and if this seems new, please file an issue. We are actively working on adding more tests for our cmake build to make it work reliably in most situations. Also, have you tried using make instead?